# Coldfusion on Linux - CFAdmin File Not found

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, coldfusion

Installation of CF9 on Ubuntu (dev environment) went fine, Apache is running, when I try to access CFADMIN I get:

The following information is meant for the website developer for debugging purposes.
Error Occurred While Processing Request
File not found: /cfide/administrator/index.cfm

CF is up and running, when I try to hit a CF page within one of the sites, I get the contents of the file printed to the screen.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, it seems the answer was as simple as incorrect case.  in the URL, I was trying to access... /cfide/administrator/index.cfm, where we all know the folder is uppercase as in CFIDE... by using the uppercase in the url, I gained access, but I figured, I would inevitabley use the lowercase in the future, I created a symbolic link in the directory with a lowercase link pointing to the uppercase directory.  This seems to work.

Please let me know if there's a better way to fix this problem.

Comment: That would do it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like Apache does not know how to read CFMs.  Make sure that the CF installer properly modified the apache config files to setup the proper script maps.  It sounds like Apache is unsure how to display .CFM files.  Also check the MIME types.  I usually run CF on Windows and IIS so I dont know the exact settings for Apache.

http://www.iknowkungfoo.com/blog/index.cfm/2008/6/8/The-ACME-Guide-64bit-Ubuntu-804-Edition-Part-2